# Why did the destroyers on Exegol rely on a navigational tower to know which way is up?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

In *Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker*, when  Poe and the others are discussing their plan to get to Exegol, Poe says:

> FINN: As long as those Star Destroyers are on Exegol we can hit them.
>
> BEAUMONT: Hit them how?
>
> ROSE: They can't activate their shields until they leave atmosphere.
>
> POE: Which isn't easy on Exegol. ***Ships that size need help taking off. Nav can't tell which way's up out there.***
>
> WROBIE TYCE: So, how do the ships take off?
>
> POE: They use a signal from a navigation tower, like this one.

Do the features of the planet itself (the magnetic fields, etc.) just inhibit any meaningful determination of "up"?

Comment: bad script writing?

Comment: You could improve this question with quotes from the movie or links to a video snippet from the movie.

Comment: Actually, any planet's features (e.g. gravity, or just simply being there) determine which way is "up" pretty effectively.

Comment: @RichS That's the answer. Attempting to make sense of out this film is an exercise in futility.

Comment: The law of Nazi FAIL: "Every overwhelming collection of Nazi forces has at least one hidden weakness that we can exploit to inflict utter defeat."

Comment: @Null They do attempt to hand wave it away with the atmosphere being really dusty (so lack of visibility) and having electrical storms which can interfere with the nav. But then immediately throw that out the window when they transfer control to another ship for the navigation.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot You don't need visibility to determine which way is "up" a gravity well. The Star Destroyers have to point their repulsorlifts "down" to avoid crashing into the planet, so the opposite direction is "up". And the Star Destroyers know which way to point their repulsorlifts because they can measure which way the ship starts to accelerate when the repulsorlifts are off (and that direction is "down").

Comment: Maybe it's just a figure of speech and just means the ships navigation doesn't work? So for example you would have trouble navigating a fleet without collisions when the ships can't tell where they and the other ships are. So you have an outside coordinator.

Comment: @Null I'm not saying the explanation makes any sense. Just that, that is the only explanation they sort of brush over for it.

Comment: They could have just looked out the window to see where the ground was

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Poe is exaggerating.

It's not that the ships literally can't tell what direction gravity is pointing, but rather that navigating a ship of that size through an atmosphere is difficult even in ideal conditions. Exegol's atmosphere is not ideal, either.

In addition to the ships involved being huge, it's also the case that the Sith fleet is huge in terms of numbers. Individual ships charting their own escape vectors would be chaos. There would be collisions left and right, followed by explosions, debris, and more collisions. Fleet actions need to be coordinated. This is why we have air traffic controllers in the real world to coordinate takeoffs even if there's only one plane!

Frankly, the unbelievable part of this is that there would only be *one tower*.

Comment: One justification for only one tower, of course, is that it reduces the risk of conflicting information. Of course, better design means that the ships will try to make a decision based off of all of the towers they can contact, but imagine the pinball chaos if they only used the closest, and one tower is saying "left" while the others are saying "right"...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots In general, if you're coordinating among multiple towers, you need a [Byzantine fault tolerant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault) system to avoid the sort of conflicting orders you're envisioning. But, most BFT implementations are meant to protect against faulty hardware, not intelligent, malicious actors.

Comment: Didn't part of that scene specifically involve the Sith trying to swap from the tower to the flagship as a 'mobile tower' or something when they realized what the New Republic forces were trying to do? It seemed like the ships were capable of acting as backup towers or relay stations in case of an emergency.